# Telegram bot | How to send an URL button with the tg: // protocol?

Tags: javascript, meteor, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot using node JS ( meteor ) and that's what's happening when I am creating a url button with a `tg://protocol`, it gives an error:

```
Error in polling: Error: failed [400] {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: unsupported URL protocol"}
```

Here is my code:

```
TelegramBot.addListener('/button', function(command, username, original) {
            TelegramBot.method('sendMessage', {
                chat_id: original.chat.id,
                text: 'Here is you proxy!',
                parse_mode: "HTML",
                reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
                    inline_keyboard: [
                        [{ text: 'Add & Connect', url: 'tg://resolve?domain=socks%26server=185.211.245.136%26port=1080%26user=106402828%26pass=jr5udGLf' }]
                    ]
                })
            });
        });
```

Comment: Why downvoted? I can't find duplicate question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `Add & Connect` with `Add &amp; Connect`

if the problem doesn't solve, replace `%26` with `&`

---

Also i offer you to use normal `https` protocol:

```
TelegramBot.addListener('/button', function(command, username, original) {
            TelegramBot.method('sendMessage', {
                chat_id: original.chat.id,
                text: 'Here is you proxy!',
                parse_mode: "HTML",
                reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
                    inline_keyboard: [
                        [{ text: 'Add & Connect', url: 'https://t.me/socks?server=*&port=*&user=*&pass=*' }]
                    ]
                })
            });
        });
```

Comment: nope, still this error : `Bad Request: unsupported URL protocol`, If I have some errors in sytnax, it's suppose to throw syntax error...